# Check if a record doesn't exist OR if a condition is true, return the parameter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-function

Given a simple table like this:

```
var1 | var2
  0  |  3
  2  |  4
  6  |  5
```

I would need to return the lowest value (var1, as a multiple of 2) for which either a record does not exist (in this case, 4) or var2 is equal to 5 (in this case, 6). I'd need to do it as a single query, but unfortunately I'm new to MySQL functions.

I tried to create a function like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION Prova ( starting_value INT ) returns int;
BEGIN
   DECLARE testNum INT DEFAULT 0;
  test_loop : LOOP
    IF (SELECT db.tabella WHERE var1 = testNum AND var2 <= 5) OR WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM db.tabella WHERE var1 = 'testNum'
) LIMIT 1; THEN
    RETURN testNum;
    END IF;
SET testNum = testNum + 2;
SELECT testNum; 
END LOOP; 

END;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by record doesn't exist ? Where/which field ?

Comment: Thank you. In the example, the records would be sorted by var1, so I'd need to return the lowest value (in this example, testNum) which is a multiple of 2 and for which there is no record with var1 = testNum. For instance: var1 = 0 -> record exists, var1 = 2 -> record exists, var1 = 4 -> record doesn't exist - return 4.

Comment: I dont think you need to use a stored function for this. It is inefficient, as it will do lots of SELECT to find out the gap. Check https://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/
It may give some idea to u :)

Comment: Thank you Madhur!

Comment: Welcome :) Try if you cant figure it out, let me know here. Will try to work out something else!

Comment: this works for sql server `select * from #Temp where var1<>0 and floor(cast(var2 as decimal)/cast(var1 as decimal)) = ceiling(cast(var2 as decimal)/cast(var1 as decimal))` dont have a working fiddle site to convert to mysql unfortunately

Comment: You have a parameter starting_value which is never used. What's its purpose?

Comment: it was an error jarlh. Thanks for pointing out.